# JBoss - How to set default data source in multi-database environment?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, datasource

I am migrating my project from JBoss EAP 6.4 to JBoss EAP 7.2.

So I am getting this kind of error,

```
   15:45:50,571 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "my.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.DefaultDataSource"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.dummy.env.myDS is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module..DefaultDataSource]"]
}
```

I got to know that this error occurs because **default data source is not defined in standalone.xml**. In previous versions of JBoss EAP removing DefaultDataSource was not giving this issue. In this version defining DefaultDataSource is mandatory even though those applications do not need that default data source.

So I tried giving default data source as an already existing datasource. In this kind of statement:

```
<default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:/jdbc/existing" />
```

And this worked fine.

Now my problem is **our environment has multiple databases and their respective data sources.**
So we can't define a particular data source as a default. As this will interfere with our applications regular flow. And can create major issues.

We want the application to use their specific data sources only not the default one.

But JBoss EAP 7 is forcing us to specify default data source.

So we can define a dummy default data source? or is there any other alternative way?

Comment: Are you sure you weren't getting the error because there was a default-datasource defined in the `ee` subsystem that had no match in the `datasource` subsystem? I find hard to believe that the default datasource became mandatory with 7.2, and I know from experience it wasn't the case with 7.0/7.1

Comment: Actually its showing error as one of my datasource is missing dependent default data source. I edited my question with actual error

Comment: I get to know giving default data source is mandate from this link https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2360921

Comment: @Aaron is there any way to solve this? and can you give me some links to refer?

Comment: Look at the resolution section : remove the `default-datasource` from the `ee`'s `default-binding` and you're good to go. the section isn't that clear, but it gives two alternative solutions : either remove the default-datasource OR redefine it

Comment: @Aaron I tried removing default-binding and it does not work. Another approach is to redefine it. My problem is our application has many datasources, I cant chose one of them as default. It can intefere with the flow. So is there any way to define dummy default data source?

Comment: Let me see if I can find another source, because I'm 95% sure you should be able to start your application without a default-datasource defined. If I'm wrong, I guess a good way to handle this would be to use system-properties defined in the server-groups which would point to a datasource that server-group actually needs. Not sure the default-datasource attribute accepts expressions though.

Comment: Eh, standalone, nevermind the server-groups then. Use any of your datasources then? If your application doesn't rely on the default-datasource this shouldn't matter. I'd just avoid the default h2 datasource that comes with the base configuration as I'd be afraid an h2 datasource would be instanciated in memory for nothing. "It can intefere with the flow. " in which way?

Comment: @Aaron I don't want it to use default data source in any case. if the application facing problems with the specific data source then I want it to raise error instead of using the default one.

Comment: Do you have any persistence-unit without a specified (non-/)jta-datasource in your persistency.xml? I think that's what would lead it to declare a dependency toward the container-defined default datasource

Answer (score 3):

default datasource option is present in default binding in standalone.xml

```
default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/jdbc/jndi-name" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It helped me in EAP 7.2 to change the default Data Source.

Answer (score 0):

Applicable to both `JBoss EAP 7.2` and `Wildfly` :

**Modify this part of standalone.xml to set the default datasource** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:3.0">
   <datasources>
      <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/default" pool-name="default" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="true">
         <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/default?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</connection-url>
         <driver>mysql</driver>
         <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
         </security>
      </datasource>
      <drivers>
         <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
            <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
         </driver>
      </drivers>
   </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

**JBoss/Wildfly will pick up this as an default datasource.**

Hope this helps you :)